# Can Web Components be used to create custom input elements?

Tags: input, submit, web-component, sample

How is it/(or just "is it?") possible to create a Web Component that can be placed inside a form and act just as any input element, that's sent to the server on submit? In other words, can Web Components be used to create custom input elements?

Comment: Example of a custom input element created by Google using Polymer: https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/demo.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following browser configuration options before testing:

- Chrome: `about:flags => Enabled Experimental WebKit Features/Enable Experimental Web Platform`
- Firefox: `about:config => dom.registercomponents.enabled`

to enable `document.registerElement`.

Use the `extends` parameter of `document.registerElement` to extend a native input element:

```
/* Cross-browser fallback */
document.registerElement = document.registerElement || document.register;
/* Element registration using x-tag format */
var MegaButton = document.registerElement('x-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
  extends: 'button'
  });
```

**References**

- [Extending Native Elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#typeextension)
- [HTML as Custom Elements](https://github.com/dglazkov/html-as-custom-elements)
- [Extending Custom Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/#extending-custom-elements)
- [Create Custom HTML Elements](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-custom-html-elements-2)
- [x-tag and the Web Components Family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Tools_and_frameworks/x-tags)
- [Performance and Custom Elements](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/11/26/performance-and-custom-elements/)
- [Mozilla: Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Tools_and_frameworks/Custom_elements)
- [Detailed Introduction to Custom Elements](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/04/introduction-to-custom-elements/)
- [Web Components: The Chromium Projects](http://chromium.org/blink/web-components)
- [Web Components Best Practices](http://webcomponents.org/articles/web-components-best-practices/)
- [Component Model Wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Component_Model)
- [Web Component Proposals: Type Extensions](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/blob/gh-pages/proposals/Type-Extensions.md)

Comment: [Here's a demo that doesn't appear to be working in Chrome or Firefox using the code you've provided](http://jsfiddle.net/sBWr2/). Am I missing something? I've double checked that I've "Enable experimental Web Platform features" set as enabled.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks for the heads up. I've [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBWr2/46/) to get it working in Firefox and found [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Buttonpresser/9W4pe/) which works using style sheet rules to define the display properties of the custom tag.

Comment: To be clear, the issue I'm having with custom elements doesn't appear to be with registration, rendering, or styling. It's when they're supposed to represent form data that things don't work. I haven't seen an example yet where a custom element can be registered so that it can be submitted as part of a form, or clicked on to submit a form.

Comment: @zzzzBov Same here. I got the example working for a [simple form submit](http://jsfiddle.net/sBWr2/66/), for what it's worth.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. The custom elements work under certain conditions. You need to use the `extends` property and do one of two things: 1. dynamically create the element with the constructor, i.e. `new MegaButton()` 2. use the `[is]` attribute on the extended element, i.e. `<button is="mega-button"></button>`. In *both* cases the element created will be the extended type (in this case `button`) which means that to style the custom element, you'd need to use `[is="mega-button"]` as a selector instead of `mega-button`. But at least these elements will work with shadow dom and forms.

Comment: @zzzzBov Can you update the jsfiddle with what you have so far?

Comment: [Here's a fiddle that works in chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/xZT7L/) where an `<input>` element is set up to use [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/). I'd have used a `<textarea>` element, but it appears that their shadow dom can't be overridden.

Comment: @zzzBov That's a good example. I saw the point about you made about adding the `[is]` attribute in one of the references, but it seemed clunky that you would need to update the markup each time you want to create a custom element. Oh well, that's design by committee.