# Can a custom element extend an input element?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Using the web components specification, is it possible to extend a specific type of `<input>` element?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623765/can-webcomponents-be-used-to-create-custom-input-elements) is similar to mine, but it only specifies how to extend a `button` element, not a text input or any other variant of the `<input>` tag.

In my case, I'd love to extend a checkbox (`<input type="checkbox" />`) or a radio button (`<input type="radio" />`) in order to wrap more complex UI around the same core input element functionality, but I don't see any way to do that using the `extends` syntax provided by `document.registerElement`. In my mind it would seem that you should be able to do something like the following:

```
document.registerElement('x-checkbox', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype),
    extends: 'input[type=checkbox]'
});
```

However, this specific case doesn't seem to be documented or explained anywhere that I can find, and I'm fairly confident that example won't work in practice.

Comment: As to extending a checkbox specifically, you could try doing `setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')` on the HTMLInputElement object before setting it as the `prototype`.

Comment: @MattBrowne That's more of a hint that it's possible than an example of how to do so. :)

Comment: @MattBrowne Part of my hope is to not have to recreate the logic of toggling a checkbox or handling which radio is checked in a group of radio buttons on my own. Not sure that setting the `type` attribute alone would solve that.

Comment: @JoshMock - Viola: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5utco0en/

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Ah, the `is` attribute. Wasn't thinking about that. You may be on to something there.

Comment: @JoshMock - I believe `is` must be used if you are extending another standard HTML element. Since there is no `checkbox` element, you cannot extend things like `input[type=checkbox]` or radio. Extend the whole input element and specify the type.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: do you know if the resulting custom element is included in form submits, like a real input?

Comment: @dandavis - it's extended from the input prototype, so it should do everything a normal input can do, however I'm not sure.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 You should turn your original comment into an answer so you get the points you deserve for it. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `is` attribute must be used if you are extending another standard HTML element. Since there is no "checkbox" element, you cannot extend things like `input[type=checkbox]` or `radio`. Extend the `input` element (`HTMLInputElement`) and specify the type in the `createdCallback`:

```
<body>
    <input is="totally-not-checkbox">   <!-- Custom Checkbox #1 -->
</body>
```

```js
var proto = Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype);
proto.createdCallback = function() {
    this.type = "checkbox";
    this.addEventListener("change", this.toggleZoom);
};
proto.toggleZoom = function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("zoom");                        //FYI $ is jQuery
};

var nCB = document.registerElement("totally-not-checkbox", {
    prototype: proto,
    extends: 'input'
});

document.body.appendChild(new nCB());  //Custom Checkbox #2
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5utco0en/

Since the custom element extends from `HTMLInputElement`, all original properties and methods are inherited. Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/6gtLp8p5/

```
proto.toggleZoom = function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("zoom");
    console.log(this, this.checked);
};
```

`this.checked` will return the correct `checked` value just like an original checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

6 years later,

I have created my own. https://elements-x.com/component/input/text
It wraps `<input>` tags with custom design and dropdown, and it supports the following types.

- text
- date
- time
- checkbox
- radio
- color
- file
- switch

[image]