# Can you 'customize' non built-in elements?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, native-web-component

In the MDN documentation for [using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), they detail an example for customizing built-in elements:

```
customElements.define('expanding-list', ExpandingList, { extends: "ul" });
```

Allowing this usage:

```
<ul is="expanding-list">

  ...

</ul>
```

I am wondering if it is possible to customize another custom element in the same way? For example, if I have created an element called `custom-element`, and I want to have variants of it, I might want to create a new `special-custom-element` class, and define it in the same way, so as to be able to use it like so:

```
<custom-element is="special-custom-element">

  ...

</custom-element>
```

However, I am prompted with an error stating:
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': "custom-element" is a valid custom element name`

When attempting to run the following:

```
customElements.define('special-custom-element', SpecialCustomElement, { extends: 'custom-element' });
```

Is this something I am doing wrong, or is this behaviour strictly limited to built-in elements? I'm finding it rather difficult to find any information about this behaviour other than what is on the page I linked to, so I was hoping for some advice from someone who knows the specs better.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that the fact that they are referring to them as 'Customized Built-Ins' and not just 'Elements' is already a sort of answer to this question, but I thought it was worth clarifying anyways!

Comment: You can only customize built-in elements. With custom element you can extend an existing class to define a new autonomous custom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it in the sense that you want since:

> There are two types of custom elements you can create:
>
> Autonomous custom element: Standalone elements; they don't inherit from built-in HTML elements.
>
> Customized built-in element: These elements inherit from — and extend — built-in HTML elements.

```
customElements.define('word-count2', WordCount2, {extends: 'p'});
```

Is for extending the `built-in elements`.

You have to go the `Autonomous custom element` route [as per the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define)

Here is an idea:

```js
// Create a class for the element
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(text) {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();
    // Create a shadow root
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    // Create the span
    var wrapper = document.createElement('span');
    wrapper.textContent = !!text ? text : 'foo';

    shadow.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
}

class MyElement2 extends MyElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super('bar');
  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
customElements.define('my-element2', MyElement2);
```

```html
<div>
  <my-element text="">
</div>
<div>
  <my-element2 text="">
</div>
```

Now you still could extend your class (*and do customization of a build-in element*) and access the output of the `super` so that might be useful to you and to some extend might allow you to get what you need:

```js
// Create a class for the element
class WordCount extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();

    // count words in element's parent element
    const wcParent = this.parentNode;

    function countWords(node) {
      const text = node.innerText || node.textContent;
      return text.split(/\s+/g).length;
    }

    const count = `Words: ${countWords(wcParent)}`;

    // Create a shadow root
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });

    // Create text node and add word count to it
    const text = document.createElement('span');
    text.textContent = count;

    // Append it to the shadow root
    shadow.appendChild(text);

    // Update count when element content changes
    text.textContent = count;
  }
}

class WordCount2 extends WordCount {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.textContent)
  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('word-count', WordCount, {
  extends: 'p'
});
customElements.define('word-count2', WordCount2, {
  extends: 'p'
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Sample heading</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar sed justo sed viverra. Aliquam ac scelerisque tellus. Vivamus porttitor nunc vel nibh rutrum hendrerit. Donec viverra vestibulum pretium. Mauris at eros vitae ante pellentesque bibendum.
    Etiam et blandit purus, nec aliquam libero. Etiam leo felis, pulvinar et diam id, sagittis pulvinar diam. Nunc pellentesque rutrum sapien, sed faucibus urna sodales in. Sed tortor nisl, egestas nec egestas luctus, faucibus vitae purus. Ut elit nunc,
    pretium eget fermentum id, accumsan et velit. Sed mattis velit diam, a elementum nunc facilisis sit amet.</p>
  <p is="word-count"></p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Sample heading</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec Sed tortor nisl, egestas nec egestas luctus, faucibus vitae purus. Ut elit nunc, pretium eget fermentum id, accumsan et velit. Sed mattis velit diam, a elementum nunc facilisis sit amet.</p>
  <p is="word-count2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: another way than using inheritance could be to create mixins with different behavior. I think JavaScript doesn't provide a language construct for it but you can easily achieve it with Object.assign.

Comment: @Akrion custom elements can have a shadow root attached to them, so I don't think that would be the reason for this sort of limitation. It's unfortunate that this limitation does exist, because it does seem a bit annoying to have to create myriad different elements just to produce one type of thing with slight variations.

Comment: I updated the answer. I think it makes more sense now.

Comment: Also added an example for the `Autonomous custom element` route

Comment: A suggestion, this QA needs better visibility/search.  Most app devs can find or infer this information, but when beginning to learn about custom elements, this is quite helpful. Googling "javascript can a custom element extend another custom element?" has this come up as an alternative under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495849/can-a-custom-element-extend-an-input-element).  Most of the other searches I tried kept this post completely buried.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this
class SpecialCustomElement extends CustomElement
{
...
}
customElements.define('special-custom-element', SpecialCustomElement, { extends: 'ul' });

and can use it as

...

Comment: It appears that your answer may have gotten cut off.